# why angularjs ui-router does not regular javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, code-injection

**UPDATE**

I am newbie for angularjs ui-router javascript framwork ,however I downloaded the sample contact application for 
describing ui-router .
according this sample you can define a controller for a `state` like this:

```
  controller: ['$scope', '$state', 'contacts', 'utils',
    function (  $scope,   $state,   contacts,   utils) {
       //blablablab 
    }]
```

i never been seen this form of javascript object definition before this .you see that controller is an array of string plus a function

my question is :

how do usual javascript interpreter,interpret this fragment of code .

```
    angular.module('uiRouterSample.contacts', [
      'ui.router'
    ]).config(
  [          '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider,   $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider

        .state('contacts', {

          abstract: true,

          url: '/contacts',

          templateUrl: 'app/contacts/contacts.html',

          controller: ['$scope', '$state', 'contacts', 'utils',
            function (  $scope,   $state,   contacts,   utils) {
               //blablablab 
            }]
        })


    }
  ]
);
```

Comment: Java **IS NOT** JavaScript.

Comment: it will continue to work just like it already is, until you minify it. (assuming you also remove the closing `]`)

Comment: Read the AngularJS documentation.

Comment: Here is a tutorial by AngularJS https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation

Comment: I am sorry , but I think that is a basic concept in angularjs , i googled it but cant find any thing that describes that concept.

Comment: @Luiggi I know that java IS NOT Javascript , I send complete code

Comment: Then please next time use proper tags for your questions.

Answer (score 2):

The parameters in the [] are the dependencies that code requires. If you do not inject the dependencies you will not have access to them. EX. $scope

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS does some sort of function inspection to guess the parameter names in the case you create a controller (or service, or factory, or any injectable stuff) like the normal javascript way:

```
function($scope, $http, otherService) {
    //bla bla bla
}
```

When this function is about to be injected (their parameters populated), the values to inject the function are fetched from an internal registry AngularJS has, by function parameter name. This means that an object registered as '$scope', another one registered by '$http', and another one registered by 'otherService' will be searched and passed to the function.

You can override this behavior, and be explicit on the injectable stuff you want the framework injects in your arguments. one of them is: give an $inject property to such function (after all, functions are an object) with the accurate names of stuff to inject:

```
var f = function(itDoesNotMatter, anymore, whichArgumentsNamesDoIUse) {
    //bla bla bla
}
f.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'otherService'];

//blablabla

$stateProvider.state({
    //...
    controller: f
})
```

And finally, the one-step solution similar to using $inject (the results are equivalent):

```
...
controller: ['$scope', '$http', 'otherService', function(x, y, z) {
    //bla bla bla
}]
```

Yes, your array has N+1 elements. The last one is an N-arity function to be populated, while the previous elements are strings = the names of services to inject.